# How do I get an error code from the CreateDIBitmap() function?

Tags: c++, image, error-handling, bitmap, null

I create a bitmap in my program using CreateDIBitmap and it has been working just fine until today.  I don't know why, but suddenly the HBITMAP it spits out is NULL, and I'm trying to debug this.  I tried using an HRESULT (can't) and GetLastError(showed no error).

Is there a way to get an error code from this function?

EDIT: as requested, here is my full bitmap setup and function call:

---

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////  Setup Bitmap  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//// FILEHEADER ////
BITMAPFILEHEADER* bf = new BITMAPFILEHEADER;
bf->bfType = 0x4d42;
bf->bfSize = 6054400 + 54 + sizeof(BITMAPINFO);
bf->bfOffBits = 54;

//// INFOHEADER ////
BITMAPINFOHEADER* bih = new BITMAPINFOHEADER;
bih->biSize = 40;
bih->biWidth = 2752;
if(mFlipVertical)
{
    bih->biHeight = -2200;
}
else
{
    bih->biHeight = 2200;
}
bih->biPlanes = 1;
bih->biBitCount = 32;
bih->biCompression = 0;
//bi->biSizeImage = 6054400; //not required
bih->biXPelsPerMeter = 2835;
bih->biYPelsPerMeter = 2835;
bih->biClrUsed = 0;
bih->biClrImportant = 0;

//// INFO ////
BITMAPINFO* pbmi = (BITMAPINFO*)alloca( sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD)*256);
pbmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof (pbmi->bmiHeader);
pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = 2752;
if(mFlipVertical)
{
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = -2200;
}
else
{
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = 2200;
}
pbmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
if(mMonoCam)
{
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 8;
}
else
{
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
}
pbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
pbmi->bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 14173;
pbmi->bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 14173;
pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

//create grayscale color palette if using mono camera
if(mMonoCam)
{
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = BYTE(i);
        pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = BYTE(i);
        pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = BYTE(i);
        pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbReserved = BYTE(0);
    }
}

//// GET IMAGE DATA ////
VmbUchar_t* imageData = NULL;
BridgedGetImage(pFrame, &imageData);

////// CREATE HBITMAP FROM IMAGE DATA //////
HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);  
HBITMAP hbit = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, bih, CBM_INIT, imageData, pbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

//let other thread know image is ready

SetEvent(img_ready_handle);

//clean up//
DeleteObject(bf);
DeleteObject(bih);
DeleteObject(hdc);
```

Comment: Well, the documentation says indeed that if the call fails, it returns NULL. Can you show us how you called CreateDIBitmap ?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I did, it returns 0.

Comment: Just wondering, but have you tried with smaller images ? (yours is 2200*2752 which seems quite big to me). I remember having issues with this once images started getting too big..

Comment: @JBL Well the frustrating thing is that until this morning I've had no problem with any of this code. All of the sudden this function decides to not create the HBITMAPs.  I can't imagine that suddenly the size is too large when I've created hundreds of thousands of bitmaps throughout the testing of my program using this exact setup.  That's why I really wish to just get an error code from this function so I can have it TELL me what it doesn't like.

Comment: I understand, and it's even more frustrating that GetLastError shows nothing. Usually it's quite straightforward. Then, the other issue I can think of is if your device context is NULL. (GetDC can return NULL, you should maybe check for that).

Comment: Have you gotten any Windows updates recently?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might have made your `BITMAPFILEHEADER` `bfSize` too big. The size of the `FileHeader` is 14 bytes the size of the infoheader is usually 40 bytes. This would be a total of 54 bytes plus the size of the pixel data along with any padding that is needed.

I think that you did not intend to do this: `bf->bfSize = 6054400 + 54 + sizeof(BITMAPINFO);`

Maybe you wanted to do this instead:  `bf->bfSize = 6054400 + 14 + sizeof(BITMAPINFO);`